# How to select CBR vs VBR through Android API while recording video in an app

Tags: android, video

I am working on an Android app that records videos. I want to be able to select between Constant Bit Rate (CBR) and Variable bit rate(VBR). I have looked at Androis API's like MediaRecoder etc. I am able to select Video bit rate, frame rate etc successfully. But I did not find any setting to select VBR vs CBR. I know video chat apps can do this so it is possible through lower layer API's. How can I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If you feed frames in with MediaCodec you can pace them however you like.  See e.g. the generated videos in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).

Comment: I am trying to produce a video with CBR so that there are no sudden spikes in bit rate. In VBR the average bit rate is maintained by the encoder at what is programmed by using a budget however there might be points in the stream where bit rate spikes. I want to have the encoder itself produce a CBR bit stream.

Comment: Android new  API MediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BITRATE_MODE, MediaCodecInfo.EncoderCapabilities.BITRATE_MODE_CBR);
but not valid i try Nexus 5, and Nexus 9, dont know what's device support this feature